# Store On Change and Later Retrieve Session Form Data

Tags: php, jquery, storage

Without going into the reasons I need to do this (it prevents rewriting a bunch of other pre-existing code), I need to store form data whenever there is a change to a form so that a user can go to another tab that may require a page refresh on certain functions. This, of course, clears the form, since the form is on the same page. My solution is to serialize the form (using jQuery) on any form change. I could store that serialized data in a PHP session variable. When the user re-selects the form tab, I could then restore the form data. I just don't know how to restore the serialized form data.
Or, perhaps, there is a more elegant way of doing this.

I am using this to serialize the form data:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var FormChanged = false;
    $('#TheForm').on('keyup change paste', 'input, select, textarea', function()
    {
        var Form = $('#TheForm').serialize();
        FormChanged = true;
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Where do you want to store the data? LocalStorage? via `.data()`? If the elements remain active in DOM, you can use `.data()` and update it upon changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lot f ways to do this. Here is one example that uses `localStorage`.

Working Example: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/ofrcza1g/

**HTML**

```
<div>
  <form id="myForm">
    <label for="myName">Name</label> <input type="text" id="myName" /><br />
    <label for="myTitle">Title</label> <input type="text" id="myTitle" /><br />
    <label for="myGender">Gender</label> <select id="myGender">
    <option></option>
    <option>Male</option>
    <option>Female</option>
    <option>Non-Binary</option>
    </select>
  </form>
</div>
<button id="myStatus">Check Status</button>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(function() {
  var dataSaved = false;

  function saveData(i, s) {
    // Input: Index, String
    // Output: Boolean
    localStorage.setItem(i, s);
    return true;
  }

  function loadData(i) {
    // Input: Index
    // Output: Parse Variable Data
    var d = localStorage.getItem(i);
    return JSON.parse(d);
  }

  function gatherData(f) {
    var d = {};
    f.find("input, select, textarea").each(function(i, el) {
      var k = $(el).attr("id");
      var v = $(el).val();
      d[k] = v;
    });
    return d;
  }

  $('#myForm').on('change blur', 'input, select, textarea', function(e) {
    var fd = JSON.stringify(gatherData($("#myForm")));
    console.log("Saving", fd);
    dataSaved = saveData("fd", fd);
  });
  $("#myForm").ready(function() {
    var fd = loadData("fd");
    console.log(fd);
    $.each(fd, function(k, v) {
      $("#" + k).val(v);
    });
  });
  $("#myStatus").click(function() {
    console.log(loadData("fd"));
  });
});
```

You can use `.serialize()` too. I just found that it relies on `name` attribute.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Perfect, Twisty! Up and running!

Comment: Actually, it seems localStorage is less than optimal. At some point, the data needs to be cleared. As far as I can tell, there is no way to do that without clearing all of the browser's stored data which could delete user's other localStorage. I tried using sessionStorage.removeItem('fd'); localStorage.removeItem('fd'); which will clear the form but it is not deleted, on refresh, the data comes back.

Comment: I guess maybe a better way would be to serialize and AJAX it into a post and store the post in a session array. Any better ideas?

Comment: @RationalRabbit that can work too if there is server side scripting. I don't know the environment or the scope of what you want to do.

Comment: More up my alley, actually. Don't know how to explain the situation concisely. Basically, different tabs on the same page. One is a table with pagination functions that either require page refreshes or the whole table section needs to be re-written using AJAX. Page refreshes, of course, will clear the form. So rather than rewrite the table section, I thought it would be less time consuming to just restore the form data on a page refresh.